# How to make UITextView's text really disappear?

Tags: iphone, uitextview

My program has a UITextView and I enter and scroll the text manually:

```
[myTextView scrollRangeToVisible:NSMakeRange([myTextView.text length]-1, 1)];
```

The text will disappear after a certain amount of input (if text length > 200)
However, when I output the content via NSLog, the text content is still valid and being updated every time I enter the text; it just won't show on myTextView

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Same problem here:

I have a UIView that I animate in and out of the screen following Touch Events.

This View has a UILabel, a UIButton and a UITextView.
Somehow the TextViews alpha, text and textColor attributes are all Ok, if I NSLog them.

EDIT: Appearently the text reappears after I try to scroll at the UITextView;

Answer (score 0):

Uh, I'm not i-developer, but can't you just set the Text to null or empty-string just after the UIView is actually made invisible? I'm sure that the platform allows you to register a "finished-callback" in the animation, that will run when the animation completes its cycle..